# Continuous functions become uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis

This is a question from a normed spaces class that eludes me.It goes like this:
"If X is a normed space such that every continuous function is uniformly continuous, then X is complete."
Just point me in the right direction. Thanks a heap

Comment: As in your other question, this doesn't make any sense. You must mean "metric", not "norm". Yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question makes little sense. If you replace the word "norm" by "metric":

Hint: Say $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence that does not converge. Define $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{d(x,x_n)}.$$You need to show that that limit exists, then show that $f$ is continuous, and finally show that it is not uniformly continuous (which follows somehow from the facts that $d(x_n,x_m)\to0$ while $f(x_n)\to\infty$, which last fact you also need to prove.)

---

Motivation for that definition; come to think of it understanding the idea may help you find the proofs of the details: That Cauchy sequence does not converge. The function $f(x)$ is morally just what $1/d(x,y)$ would be if there *were* a point $y$ with $x_n\to y$. In particular it blows up at that point that's not there...

Comment: Yes it is a metric, thanks!